# How can I write a method to easily create different types of subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, factory

For a project I have to create objects that represent different types of users. All types are subclasses inheriting from superclass User. In the example we have a Student, Teacher and a Coordinator. Every class has different implementations of certain methods.
To know what kind of user we are dealing with, a record is pulled from a database, including a user role. Depending on the role, a different type of User subclass is created.
Currently I am using a switch statement a seen below. However, since they all have identical constructors, this results in very repetitive code. How could this be done more elegant/efficiently?

```
public void makeUserTypes() {
        switch (idRole) {
            case 0:
                user = new Student(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
                break;
            case 1:
                user = new Teacher(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
                break;
            case 2:
                user = new Coordinator(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to have an Enumeration with the types of roles and then simply have a User type with an extra field called role? Assuming those are just data classes. And then when you need to do some logic you make a switch on the role.

Comment: Every type has their own implementation of certain methods

Comment: Other way is using reflection where the role you get from the database can be mapped in a type name and then you just instantiate that type.

Comment: Reflection sounds interesting, I am relatively new to programming and java. That would be by using Class.forName() ?

Comment: There's more than just that since you need to pass parameters to the constructor. Try looking at [this](https://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=JavaReflection/Constructors.php).

Comment: Why not just using the power of interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a functional interface, with a switch or map?

```
public interface UserCtor<U> {
  U create(String idUser, String username, String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
public void makeUserTypes() {
    UserCtor<?> ctor = null;
    switch (idRole) {
        case 0:
            ctor = Student::new;
            break;
        case 1:
            ctor = Teacher::new;
            break;
        case 2:
            ctor = Coordinator::new;
            break;
    }
    user = ctor.create(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
}
```

Or you can use a map:

```
private static Map<Integer, UserCtor<?>> ctorMap = Map.of(
    0, Student::new,
    1, Teacher::new,
    2, Coordinator::new
);

public void makeUserTypes() {
    user = ctorMap.get(idRole).create(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
}
```

Or an array (which I wouldn't recommend because it assumes that `idRole` starts at 0 and doesn't skip numbers)

```
private static UserCtor<?>[] ctors = {Student::new, Teacher::new, Coordinator::new};

public void makeUserTypes() {
    user = ctors[idRole].create(idUser, username, firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will look into it tomorrow, see if I can figure it out. I assume ctor.create() would take parameters right?

Comment: @manolo Yeah, my bad. I forgot to add them :/ Fixed it now

Comment: I went for implementation with Map. Works like a charm!